# Prevent div from wrapping around in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to help structure a webpage. Within a row, I have three divs side-by-side, with widths: 2 columns, 6 columns, and 4 columns in that order in a 12 column layout.

The middle div also has a minimum width set, so when the outermost div shrinks beyond a certain width, there is not enough room for the right most div (the 4 column one), so it wraps around and hangs out below the other divs.

I would like to prevent this div from wrapping around, forcing it to be cut off by the window when the screen shrinks too small. How would I accomplish this?

I can provide any further details/code/pictures if necessary.

Thanks!

[Before wrapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b5yq.png)

[After wrapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBMmu.png)

Comment: It will be good if you can show us the scenario using fiddle/snippet

Comment: Any added padding?  Are these three wrapped in a div with .row?

Comment: @AndrewIce These divs are wrapped in a row, inside a container

Comment: Your min-width could cause this to break.  The display flex would help this issue but honestly, this would not be recommended if you're aiming to have a responsive screen.  The columns are percentage based.  If your middle column breaches that width, there is no choice but for the DOM to push the next element down.

Comment: @AndrewIce Any recommendations?

Comment: Hmm, is there a specific reason as to why you need this width specifically?  Other than to contain all of the elements in the table?

Comment: @AndrewIce would like to have all the divs stay the same size once the window grows beyond a certain size i.e. Just have whitespace on the sides

Comment: The container class should stop at a specific width already.  Perhaps you just need to adjust the width at which the container class stops.  And not on the center element.

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#grid-options

Comment: @AndrewIce I would also like the divs to simply be cut off when the screen shrinks beyond a certain point, however. I'm not sure how that will accomplish this

Comment: Bootstrap is built on responsiveness, so you may have a few hoops to jump through there.  I can't say I support the choice.  But your best approach there would be to set a min-width on the container class.  ( At least for that specific element ) based on where you want the cut off to be.  And then set an overflow of auto/scroll.  Something along those lines.

Comment: @AndrewIce Is there a way I can cap the height of the red outermost div? The table will usually be as tall as the leftmost div, so perhaps this could prevent the rightmost div from wrapping around? Setting the max-height for the outermost div does not seem to work

Comment: As stated before.  The display: flex comment below would help that issue.  If you set your row to display flex.  All direct child elements of the flexbox should retain the same size as one another.  Height wouldn't stop the divs from wrapping, only the width would.  You could set a height on the red element container as well, and also do overflow scroll.  But I still wouldn't recommend it.  It would sit at whatever width you have chosen. 

I am mostly making assumptions at how your code is built at the time being.  Not code to go off of.

Comment: How is this off-topic? Seems like a common issue as it has been viewed three thousand times!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent wrapping: add this to your row.

```
.row{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:flex;
}
```

`width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;` are optional in this.

This may cause your content to stretch to full height, so don't put content in bootstrap columns(e.g. `col-md-6 and so on) directly. put a div in them and put the content inside that div.

like this :

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <div class="contentDiv">
    <!--Put your content here-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's an example:

```css
#firstDiv,#secondDiv,#thirdDiv{
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  min-width:100px;
}
#firstDiv{
  background-color:green;
}
#secondDiv{
  background-color:blue;
  min-width:500px;
}
.row{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2" id="firstDiv">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" id="secondDiv">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4" id="thirdDiv">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm this seems to cause the divs to overlap once the minimum width is hit

Comment: okay. you need to add `class="clearfix"` to bootstrap divs (e.g. `col-md-2` and so on)

Comment: It worked! A little messy but it did what you said. Thanks